# returning Collection after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm using `Spring data jpa` and `Spring MVC` and I make a ajax call call to update jsp page but i got error in google chorme:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/pagesjaunes/loadfonction 500 (Erreur Interne de Servlet)         jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
send                    jquery-1.10.2.js:8706
x.extend.ajax           jquery-1.10.2.js:8136
(anonymous function)    ajoutcontact.js:15
x.event.dispatch        jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
v.handle                jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

my ajax call looks like that:

```
        $.ajax({
            url : 'loadfonction',
            type : 'post',
            data : { "idquality" : idquality },
            success : function(fonctions) {   
                                [...]
            },      
            error : function(){
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loadfonction") 
public @ResponseBody
Set<Fonction> loadfonction(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) { 

    return qualiteRepo.findOne(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("idquality"))).getFonctions();

}
```

`Fonction` is my entity mapped:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fonction", catalog = "pagesjaunes")
public class Fonction implements java.io.Serializable {
      [...]
}
```

what is worng with `Set<Fonction>` ? because i test other code and it's work :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/loadfonction") 
public @ResponseBody
Set<Fonction> loadfonction(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) { 


    Set<String> test = new HashSet<String>(0);
    test.add("yous");
    test.add("cc");
    test.add("fz");


    return test;

}
```

my entity `Fonction`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fonction", catalog = "pagesjaunes")
public class Fonction implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
private Qualite qualite;
private String nom;
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0);
private Set<Domaine> domaines = new HashSet<Domaine>(0);

public Fonction() {
}

public Fonction(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public Fonction(String nom, Qualite qualite) {
    this.qualite = qualite;
    this.nom = nom;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_qualite")
public Qualite getQualite() {
    return this.qualite;
}

public void setQualite(Qualite qualite) {
    this.qualite = qualite;
}

@Column(name = "nom", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fonction")
public Set<Contact> getContacts() {
    return this.contacts;
}

public void setContacts(Set<Contact> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "fonction_domaine", catalog = "pagesjaunes", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_fonction", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_domaine", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Domaine> getDomaines() {
    return this.domaines;
}

public void setDomaines(Set<Domaine> domaines) {
    this.domaines = domaines;
}

}
```

Comment: Could you provide the server-side stacktrace if any?

Comment: nothing happened at server-side !

Comment: Does `request.getParameter("idquality")` return the expected value? If yes, `qualiteRepo.findOne(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("idquality")))` returns the expected `Qualite` (I presume) too?

Comment: yes data is retrieving right from database i try `qualiteRepo.findOne(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("idquality"))).getFonctions().size()` and he return the right size.

Comment: What if you use `int loadfonction(...)` and then return the size of the list like you stated above? Do you still get the error?

Comment: no i got no error and i receive in ajax success the right size.

Comment: Could you provide the body of your `Fonction` class?

Comment: i update my post take a look.

Comment: Could you try to replace every `FetchType.LAZY` by `FetchType.EAGER` in your `Fonction` entity? Please notice that, even if the error may come from this point, this won't be a suitable solution in the end. Just let me know if there is no error anymore.

Comment: i replace them but i still got error !

Comment: Try to add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation from the package `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate` on the following methods of your `Fonction` class, and see if error still occurs: `getQualite()`, `getContacts()` and `getDomaines()`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45930/discussion-between-sp00m-and-youssef)

Comment: ok finally it's work with `@JsonIgnore` thanks @sp00m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a lazy loading error. Strange that you've no stacktrace server-side btw. If you're using a logging tool such as log4j or logback, check your configuration to append any output to your console.

One simple solution would be to add the @JsonIgnore annotation on the lazy loading getters in your `Fonction` entity.

But the best solution would be to create a new web-side plain POJO that stores only the attributes you're looking to in your `success` AJAX callback.

For example, if you need only the `id` and the `nom` attributes of your `Fonction` entity:

```java
public class WebFonction implements Serializable {

    private int id;
    private String nom;

    public WebFonction(Fonction fonction) {
        id = fonction.getId();
        nom = fonction.getNom();
    }

    // getters and setters

}
```

Then, in your controller, instead of returninig a `Set<Fonction>`, you would return a `Set<WebFonction>`:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/loadfonction", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
@ResponseBody
public Set<WebFonction> loadfonction(@RequestParameter Integer idquality) { 
    Set<Fonction> fonctions = qualiteRepo.findOne(idquality).getFonctions();
    Set<WebFonction> webFonctions = new HashSet<WebFonction>();
    for (Fonction fonction : fonctions) {
        webFonctions.add(new WebFonction(fonction));
    }
    return webFonctions
}
```

Comment: thanks but i think `@JsonIgnore `is the best solution because with new pojo and if we have a lot of entity there will be a lot of repeat of code.

Comment: Alright, but be aware that every field/getter annotated with @JsonIgnore won't be serialized and thus accessible in your AJAX success callback.